# How to align all of my divs perfectly?

Tags: css, html, containers

My three columns are not aligning properly with everything else? My header, footer, featured is all aligned but that's because it's a single div and not multiple.
demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Zevoxa/3LDUd/

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>LOGO</h1>
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="feature"><div style="text-align:center">
            <p>Feature<p>
        </div>
        <div class="article column1">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="article column2">
            <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="article column3">
            <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio.</p>
        </div>
    </div></div>
    <div id="footer"><div style="text-align:center">
        <p>&copy; Copyright 2013</p>
    </div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/3LDUd/1/

You had the width set to 33.3px instead of percent.

```
.column1, .column2, .column3 {
        background-color: #efefef;
        width: 30%;
        float: left;
        margin: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
 }
```

Comment: But they are still not properly aligned with everything else like featured and the footer?

Comment: What is the CSS for "article"

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/3LDUd/3/   This lines up nice.  You set a fixed width of 1330px, so I set a fixed width on the div's as well. Let me know what you think!

Comment: remove `float:left` if you're setting inline-block mode, and add `vertical-align:top`

Comment: The width should be: width: 416.66667px;  since you have a Body width of 1330px, with padding of 10px on both sides.  Then you have all the divs with a margin of 10px also.  So you have 10+10 for the body, plus 10+ (10 + 10) + (10 + 10) + 10 on the divs, which comes to 1250px remaining.  Divide 1250px by 3 and you get 416.66667

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I simply made up a mock up in photoshop of what I'm trying to achieve. http://i.imgur.com/SfFQDyi.png

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/3LDUd/4/  Here, you had the column divs nested instead the feature div.  I opened moved the </div> from after the column divs to before.  How's that?

Comment: If this solved your question, please thank me by clicking on the check mark for me!  Thanks!

Comment: One more tiny problem. The columns are still not aligned with the right side of the page. I tried editing the margin in ".column1, .column2, .column3" and it just messed it up.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/3LDUd/5/  That was because the Feature div had margins of 10px, so I recalculated the width including all margins - this time only the margins of the column divs - 10 + 20 + 20 + 10 = 60.  1330 - 60 = 1270.  1270 / 3 = 423.3333px

Answer (score 1):

I've made the widths of the articles 33% and instead put the 10px margin around the

tag within it. Also added a clearer div, check it out here:

http://jsfiddle.net/dzHgX/

```
.column1, .column2, .column3 {
    background-color: #efefef;
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
.column1 p, .column2 p, .column3 p {
    margin: 10px;
}
```